# Trane XR80 furnace fan not working

Tags: furnace

The red light is 4 flashing times. I’m hoping it’s the simple fix by replacing the capacitor. Does anyone know what the hp of the stock fan motor is if the capacitor doesn’t fix the problem? I don’t know if the fan motor is 1/2 hp or 1/3 hp without taking out the entire assembly.

Update:
I am an idiot and when I did the bypass test to check if the fan has power I disconnected the wrong wire and unhooked the power supply. Duh, no wonder why I didn’t have power to the fan. Anyways I was able to bypass the IFC and the fan works! Also I found on the back side of the panel cover was the light codes. Turns out that it wasn’t 4 flashes but a continuous glass which means I need to replace the IFC.

Comment: 10 seconds of search says the 4 flash is the high limit, (which is expected if the fan does not start/run) and the high limit should reset itself. While folks do love to throw capacitors at HVAC motors, that's only one of several possible issues, and without debugging, it's just throwing parts at the problem and hoping one will stick.

Comment: Glad you got this working! If you'll take the [tour], you'll learn that this place works a little differently than others. Instead of editing your original question to include your answer, it's preferred that you write up an answer of your own (self-answers are 100% acceptable) if you want to share the results of what you did. After all, if the answer is in the question, there's no point in reading the answers...

Answer (score 0):

4 flashes means open high temperature limit device

It could be broken or it could be reporting correctly

The high temp limit switches usually have a manual reset button that needs to be pressed to reset.

Try a reset first, if the reset doesn't trip again it is probably fine.

If it trips again you will want to verify the exhaust and filter is clear.

Next check if the fan is freely spinning (some do need oil at each end to lube the bearings)

Comment: *check if the fan is freely spinning*, +1. It's two screws after you remove the CB. Just pull the thing out.... *after* you've verified the safety chain. Then you can look up there and check the coil too for dust bunnies. It's not a common problem but it's one you can't find w/o pulling the blower.

Comment: I can’t find where the manual reset button is for the high limit sensor is. I disconnected the wires to it and took it out and inspected it. I’m still getting the light to flash but it now seems to be continuously blinking.